# React dynamic component cannot access prop function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state, react-functional-component

I am trying to access a prop function within a child component which ultimately changes a state within a parent component. Here is how it works:

**parent.tsx**

```
const initialData = {
  spanish: "",
};

const [inputData, setInputData] = useState(initialData);

const getData = (data: Object) => {
  const obj = { ...inputData, ...data };
  setInputData(obj);
};
```

**child.tsx**

**child** built like:

```
<input
  id={props.language + "Input"}
  name={props.language + "Input"}
  placeholder={"Type a word in " + props.language}
  type="text"
  value={input}
  onChange={handleInput}
/>
```

**child** is used like this inside of parent:

```
<LanguageInput language={"spanish"} getValue={getData} />
```

```
const [input, setInput] = useState("");
const [data, setData] = useState({});

const handleInput = (e: any) => {
  setInput(e.target.value);
};

useEffect(() => {
  let obj = {
    [props.language]: input,
  };
  setData(obj);
}, [input]);

useEffect(() => {
  props.getValue(data);
}, [data]);
```

The problem arises when I try to dynamically generate the child component based on user input (the user would insert the language and the component will be added for that language).

When I use the component statically, the setInputData(obj) behaves as expected and gets the updated state from other static **child** components, but when I try inputing anything into the dynamic **child** component, it gets the initialData object or its own data while not preserving anything else that the user has put into the other fields.

For example: 1 dynamically generated component handling the spanish language + 3 statically generated components handling 3 other languages would behave as follows:

1. User inputs "a" into the dynamic component and the getData() "obj" will = "{spanish: a}"
2. User inputs "b" into the 1st static component and the getData() "obj" will = "{spanish: a, spanishStatic1: b}"
3. User inputs "c" into the 2nd static component and the getData() "obj" will = "{spanish: a, spanishStatic1: b, spanishStatic2: c}"
4. User inputs "d" into the 3rd static component and the getData() "obj" will = "{spanish: a, spanishStatic1: b, spanishStatic2: c, spanishStatic3: d}"
5. Now if a user types another "a" in the first field which is the dynamic one the result will be "spanish: aa" and everything else will be lost.

Updating any of the statically generated components will not lose any data, but once a dynamic component is updated, all the data is lost as it cannot read or write via state.

How do I got around that or fix it so that the dynamically generated component updates the parent state and it works? The ultimate goal is to have only dynamically generated components or only 1 static and everything else dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is put

```
const initialData = {
  spanish: "",
};
```

outside the parent component...

Second thing I would do is

Parent component

```
const [inputData, setInputData] = useState(initialData);

const setNewData = useCallback((newData) => {
   setInputData({...inputData, ...newData})
}, [inputData, setInputData])

<LanguageInput language={"spanish"} setNewData={setNewData} />
```

Child component

```
const [input, setInput] = useState("");

const handleInput = (e: any) => {
  setInput(e.target.value);
  props.setNewData({
     [props.language]: e.target.value,
  })
};
```

Comment: With those changes, not even the static components carry over progress. Only the latest input saves its data, everything else gets lost.

Edit: I messed up some of the code, but it still doesn't work after fixing it the way you have written it. Same effect as before, dynamic loses data, static keeps data.